# Chromium browser KIOSK hanging or freezing

Tags: node.js, chromium, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, kiosk-mode

I have a web application using NodeJs to display status of hardware. I am using raspberry pi 3 b+ with 18 inch monitor, MI charger 5V3A, 32 GB SD card, Raspios-bullseye operating system  to do this. It has been working last 15 days without any problems now the kiosk hanging or freezing one time in every 2 days. Communication with hardware still working when kiosk hanging. Only can solve by relaunch kiosk or restart.

What may the reason for this? How to solve this issue automatically?

Comment: could be a power supply problem

Comment: if it is power supply problem, i think the raspberry pi board should completely hang.@FlashThunder

Comment: not really, could be still working, but didn't have enough juice to properly calculate things for one of the apps - we had such a problems before with RPI3. In fact because of that we have decided to stop using Raspberries at all.